# Android and Elevation Data

Tags: android, maps, gis, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to build a simulator which needs to know what the terrain looks like in front of a given location.

I know that we can get elevation data from the [National Elevation Dataset](http://eros.usgs.gov/#/Find_Data/Products_and_Data_Available/NED), but once I have it.. I'm pretty lost.

I was reading through the comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090534/how-to-look-up-elevation-data-by-lat-lng), and the answers make sense, but I can't run a Postgres server for the data on Android like they can for a website that needs the same information.

I need to be able to load the elevations for points a given distance in front of my current GPS lat/long, so I need to be able to search the dataset.

Additionally, I need this to work without a data connection, so it has to all be on the phone with no network needed other than a GPS connection.

Where should I start? I'm pretty much lost =\

I guess, what I need is.... I have the elevation data in ArcGRID or GRIDFLOAT format from the USGS. Now what? I can't find good examples of working with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has SQLite baked right in so you can use this to store your data and then search through it as required. [Start here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) and I'm sure you'll find what you're looking for.

You can also review the "[searchable dictionary](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html)" example Google has up for a good how-to on searching within a content provider.

**Update:** For working with the ArcGRID stuff, again, this is beyond my realm of expertise, but I did find a general Java based toolset called [GeoTools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geotools/) that has code that works with spatial databases. You may be able to pull this code down and analyze how it's working with the other data providers and then base your design on SQLite to emulate this? There is also [a tutorial on querying](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/filter/query.html).

**Update 2:** Check out the [Android Documentation on GeoTools](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GEOTOOLS/Android). Some good information there as well.

Comment: That works for storing the data, but it comes as a raster image. Does this mean that the "best design" is something like this? 1. Convert raster elevation data into SQL inserts. 2 - upload to phone, insert into DB, 3 - query for data along a given lat/long path.

Comment: I guess, what I need is.... I have the elevation data in ArcGRID or GRIDFLOAT format from the USGS.     Now what? I can't find good examples of working with the data.

Comment: I don't have much on that stuff, does this link help with anything? http://androidgps.blogspot.com/2008/11/displaying-usgs-earthquake-data-on.html

Comment: Not really.. what I'm really trying to find is information on working with ArcGrid or GridFloat data and visualizing it.

Comment: Added an update on GeoTools for you. I'm learning a lot while trying to help you figure this one out at least! ;-)

Comment: Oh, and digging deeper, I found an Android reference on their wiki here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GEOTOOLS/Android

Comment: Very helpful. I had seen GeoTools before, but not their android documentation. That's really helpful!

Comment: Good to hear man. Hope it all works out well for yah! Thanks for the learning opportunity too eh!

Comment: So in digging through that documentation I hit upon someone commenting about creating a heightmap from the USGS data. That's pretty much what I needed to do.. and now I can use any random game engine with a heightmap created from the Digital Elevation Model data from the USGS Seamless service.