# Get altitude data from Google Earth

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth

I am trying to get the altitude of some points given their latitude and longitude. Is there any api to do this in Google Earth? I need to deal with a large amount of data.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=altitude+data+google+maps+api

Answer (score 3):

Google provides an elevation API for up to 25k requests per day: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/

There are also the other options discussed here: [How to look up elevation data by lat/lng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090534/how-to-look-up-elevation-data-by-lat-lng)

Comment: Note: Google Elevation API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map and using elevation data without displaying a map for which elevation data was requested is prohibited by Google's policy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data in a spreadsheet form, you can input it into GPS Visualizer (http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/convert_input) and select "Add DEM elevation data", and it will return with a text file with the elevation data in a column.